# is there anyway to test google webhook without having any registered domain over ssl?

Tags: webhooks, google-domain-api

I am writing something where my program expecting a **webhook callback** when something changes on google drive in a specific file, I am through with business logic however I am unable to get webhook callbacks as I don't have any secured domain over SSL, could anyone please suggest any alternative way to test these webhook callbacks in development environment ? appreciate every read and comment.

Answer (score 2):

If you own a domain you can forward it to AWS servers and they provide free SSL certs, Otherwise you can use the service LetsEncrypt https://letsencrypt.org/ to secure your website.